# In app Purchase after showing demo pages

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, in-app-purchase

I am working on a Story books Application. In which client wants to show 2 pages as free demo and to see remaining other pages he need to buy the book. Somebody please tell me is it allowed by apple cause I just heard that apple is not allowing it.

**Please guys help me. *I have never worked on In App Purcahse.***

Comment: Try this demo for ios 6: http://www.raywenderlich.com/23266/in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial-consumables-and-receipt-validation

Answer (score 1):

It's allowed as an in-app purchase as long as that book is a digital purchase and cannot be taken out of the application.

As for the last line, see the related [programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).